# FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.8.0)` required by `Podfile`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Using Xcode 7.1 swift with the following pods

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

  pod "Bolts", "1.4.0"
  pod "FBSDKCoreKit", "4.8.0"
  pod "FBSDKLoginKit", "4.8.0"
  pod "FBSDKShareKit", "4.8.0"
```

Adding `FBSDKCoreKit` is the one giving me the error using `pod install --verbose`:

```
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.8.0)` required by `Podfile`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:411:in `handle_resolver_error'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:69:in `rescue in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:57:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:539:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:537:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:70:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:213:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:136:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:135:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:105:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Do you know why?

Update info cocoa pods version:
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (0.39.0)
cocoapods-core (0.39.0)
cocoapods-downloader (0.9.3)
cocoapods-plugins (0.4.2)
cocoapods-search (0.1.0)
cocoapods-stats (0.6.2)
cocoapods-trunk (0.6.4)
cocoapods-try (0.5.1)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some context around the error? There should be more information printed with it.

Comment: Update: just used "pod install --verbose"

Comment: Can you attach the full Podfile? (Or is it just those 4 lines?)

Comment: I've never seen that before, usually there's a conflict between a couple sources. Have you tried running pod update, then pod install again? FBSDKCoreKit 4.8 seems to only be 13 hours old, it might be possible that Cocoapods on your machine just doesn't know it exists.

Comment: Update: I am using use_frameworks!

Comment: @ChrisG. I assume you're getting the same error after running `pod update`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - the exact same error.

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using? You can see by running `gem list cocoapods`.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question.